# count the the number of 1s in its binary representation -- shift right don't work?

Tags: python

when asked the question to count the number of 1s in the binary representation , the first answer came to my mind is to shift the number right and count the least important bit

but there is a saying that when the number is negative , this method will cause infinite loop ?

I tried quickly with python

```
>>> a = -16
>>> a >> 1
-8
>>> a >> 1
-8
>>> -8 >> 1
-4
>>>
```

this is what I expect, so what is the issue, will shift the negative number cause the sign bit to be carried over to the right ?

Comment: How wide are your numbers? If we're talking about unlimited-precision integers, then any negative number has an infinite number of 1's! If we're talking 32-bit or 64-bit ints, just shift this many times and stop.

Comment: @alexis yes, I am talking about 32bits in c++, seems I am confused by python implementation of >>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we're talking about python's unlimited-precision integers, then any negative number has an infinite number of 1's! So regardless of sign-filling (which you'll also get in C), counting the bits in a negative number is non-sensical except for a fixed bit length.

For a 32-bit or 64-bit int, just shift this many times and stop.

Here are the bits in the 32-bit integer -4.

```
>>> n = -4
>>> for bit in reversed([ (n>>shift)&1 for shift in range(32) ]):
...    print bit,
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 0
```

So to sum them up, it's just

```
sum( (n>>shift)&1 for shift in range(32) )
```

Answer (score 3):

It's true, you will get an infinite loop, because once you get to `-1` you can't get out of there:

```
>>> a = -1
>>> a >> 1
-1
```

This sounds like homework so I won't give you a full answer, but have a look at the built-in `mod` function.

Answer (score 2):

See http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#shifting-operations: shifting to the right is equivalent with dividing. Then check http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#binary-arithmetic-operations: integer divisions implicitely apply `floor` on the result, so `-1 / 2 = -1` since `floor(-0.5) = -1`, and regardless of the number you start with, you'll finally reach -1. Therefore, you'll end up with an infinite loop.